# How to interpret the notation for calculating IV for AES counter mode in SRTP implemetation

Tags: java, c#

I am trying to do a C# implementation of SRTP based on RFC 3711.
In section 4.1.1 in the RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3711#section-4.1.1) is the following notation on how to calculate IV for AES counter mode:

IV = (k_s * 2^16) XOR (SSRC * 2^64) XOR (i * 2^16)

k_s is a 14 byte key salt.

SSRC is used to identify the RTP stream.

i is the packet index

My SRTP implementation is based on a Java implementation which can be found here:
https://github.com/LucaBongiorni/ZORG/blob/master/zorg-java/src/zorg/SRTP.java

The Java code for calculating IV is the following

```
    private void initialiseIV(byte[] iv, long ssrc, int seq, long roc, byte[] aSessSaltKey) {
    // First calculate initial IV for encryption
    // from rfc3711:
    // IV = (k_s * 2^16) XOR (SSRC * 2^64) XOR (i * 2^16)
    // k_s is session salt key
    // SSRC from RTP Packet
    // i is SRTP SEQ num (i.e. iROC+seq)

    platform.getUtils().zero(iv);

    System.arraycopy(aSessSaltKey, 0, iv, 0, 14);

    // IV now contains k_s * 2^16, since k_s is 14 bytes long
    // Now xor with SSRC*2^64 - aSsrc is a long only to make it unsigned,
    // only 4 LSB of interest
    for (int i = 4; i < 8; ++i) {
        byte b = (byte) ((ssrc >>> ((7 - i) << 3)) & 0xFF);
        iv[i] = (byte) (b ^ iv[i]);
    }

    // initVector now contains (k_s*2^16) XOR (SSRC*2^64)
    iv[13] = (byte) ((seq & 0xff) ^ iv[13]);
    iv[12] = (byte) (((seq >>> 8) & 0xff) ^ iv[12]);

    long tempROC = roc >>> 16; // Only a long to make it unsigned, only 4
        // bytes of interest

    for (int i = 11; i >= 8; --i) {
        iv[i] ^= (byte) (tempROC & 0xFF);
        tempROC = tempROC >>> 8;
    }
}
```

I have done the same code in C#

```
    private void InitialiseIV(byte[] iv, long ssrc, int seq, long roc, byte[] aSessSaltKey)
    {
        // First calculate initial IV for encryption
        // from rfc3711:
        // IV = (k_s * 2^16) XOR (SSRC * 2^64) XOR (i * 2^16)
        // k_s is session salt key
        // SSRC from RTP Packet
        // i is SRTP SEQ num (i.e. iROC+seq)

        Array.Copy(aSessSaltKey, 0, iv, 0, 14);

        // IV now contains k_s * 2^16, since k_s is 14 bytes long
        // Now xor with SSRC*2^64 - aSsrc is a long only to make it unsigned,
        // only 4 LSB of interest
        for (int i = 4; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            byte b = (byte)((ssrc >> ((7 - i) << 3)) & 0xFF);
            iv[i] = (byte)(b ^ iv[i]);
        }

        // initVector now contains (k_s*2^16) XOR (SSRC*2^64)

        iv[13] = (byte)((seq & 0xff) ^ iv[13]);
        iv[12] = (byte)(((seq >> 8) & 0xff) ^ iv[12]);

        long tempROC = roc >> 16; // Only a long to make it unsigned, only 4

        // bytes of interest
        for (int i = 11; i >= 8; --i)
        {
            iv[i] ^= (byte)(tempROC & 0xFF);
            tempROC = tempROC >> 8;
        }
    }
```

My SRTP implementation gives the correct result for the test vectors found here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3711#appendix-B.2

But when attempting to encrypt a RTP packet I do not get the same encrypted payload as other commercial SRTP implementations encrypting the same packet. So any help on how to interpret the IV notation from the RFC, or help to understand how the java implementation of the InitializeIV method works would be a big help.

Comment: And why are you sure that your implementation fails specifically because of this function? I guess there are more functions in implementation.

Comment: I am not 100% sure that it is this function that fails. I get the correct results for the AES-CM test vectors and the key derivation test vectors from RFC 3711. This means that the implementation gives the correct result when the parameters ssrc, seq and roc are all 0.

Comment: When the parameters are all 0 the only effect of the InitializeIV method is that the 14 bytes salt key is copied into a 16 bytes array.

Because I don't have a test example where the input parameters are not 0, it is difficult to determine if the method is correct. So I would like som help in understanding the meaning of the IV notation.